# Ordering points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ using the sign of determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Is there any way to order $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ using DETERMINANT?(Points are in general position, means no three are collinear.)
I can do that in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

For every $3$ points in the plane, we can compute determinant from the matrix, where lines are coordinates of points (3rd coordinate is 1). If the determinant is > 0, points are in clockwise order. If not, we can switch, for example, last two points and we will get the Clockwise order.

If points are $A, B, C,$ then your matrix looks like:

\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{A}       & y_{A} & 1 \\
   x_{B}       & y_{B} & 1\\
    x_{C}       & y_{C} & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Then we compare determinant of the above matrix with zero. If it's > 0, return points A, B, C, if it isn't, return A, C, B.

I was wondering if there is an extension of this way for $\mathbb{R}^3$?
I couldn't find anything :(( Any help will be appriciated!

Comment: What if the points are co-linear in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Irrespective of what order you write the points in, the determinant will be zero, giving no information about the order. For instance, points (1,1), (2,1) and (3,1) in that  order are counterclockwise, and (3,1), (2,1), (1,1) are clockwise.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. Points are in general position, means no three are collinear. Thank you.

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}^3$, ordering $ n\leq 3$ points can be extrapolated from the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case. For $n=4$,you might want to look at scalar triple product. It is generally used to find coplanarity of 3 vectors, but I think the sign of the determinant should be able to convey order in certain sense.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I don't really see how this is an "order" in the strict sense. Even in $\Bbb R^2$, this would give $x<y<z<x$ if $ x,y,z$ are vectors evenly spaced on the unit circle. Right?

Comment: @Arthur: It is kind of ordering. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ it tells us if the points are ordered clockwise or anticlockwise.

Comment: That would typically be called orientation, rather than ordering. And in $\Bbb R^3$ the common names for the two orientations are "right-handed" and "left-handed".

Comment: Can we prove it using determinant?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this snippet from [*Computational Geometry in C*](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/books/compgeom.html) will help
you understand the generalization:

---

[image: CG1]

[image: CG2]

---